# Probability That Someone's Number Choice is Greater Than the Others

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My friend and I are selecting numbers independently, and we both select a number from the set
$\{1, \cdots, 10\}$. What is the probability that I select a number strictly larger than my friends. We can choose the same number.

I am stuck on this problem. I know that we can use $P(E) = \frac{|E|}{|S|}$ and that our sample space $|S| = 10$.

I don't know exactly how to proceed. If I choose $10$ than I'll have the largest number, but this doesn't really help me solve this. Suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Assuming you both choose uniformly at random, then the probability of a tie is $.1$ so the probability that you choose different numbers is $.9$  Can you finish from there?

Comment: I think so! So we have two different probabilities over the same sample space. Would we multiply these two probabilities together? So the probability of a tie and probability that I have a greater number than my friend?

Comment: I think the sum of the probabilities you picking a number $n$ multiplied by your friend pickings a number less than $n$ will give you the probability. In this case: $\sum_{n = 1}^{10} P(n)\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}P(m) = \dfrac{1}{10}\bigg(\dfrac{0 +\dots + 9}{10}\bigg)= 0.45$ will be the probability.($P(a)$ is the probability of picking $a$.

Comment: No...either there is a tie or there is a winner (i.e. someone has a higher score).  The probability that there is a winner is $\frac 9{10}$ so, since it is equally likely that you or your friend is the winner, the probability that you are the winner is $\frac 12\times \frac 9{10}=\frac 9{20}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the number chosen by your friend and you be $X,Y\in\{1,...,10\}$ respectively.
$$P(Y>X)=P([X=1\text{ and }Y>1]\text{ or }[X=2\text{ and }Y>2]\text{ or...or }[X=9\text{ and }Y>9])\\=\sum_{x=1}^9P(X=x\text{ and }Y>x)$$because all events are disjoint. Since $X,Y$ are independent, we get$$\sum_{x=1}^9P(X=x)\times P(Y\in\{x+1,x+2,...,10\})=\sum_{x=1}^9\frac1{10}\times\frac{10-x}{10}=0.45.$$

---

Alternatively, there are $10\times 10=100$ equiprobable ordered pairs $(X,Y)$ out of which $Y>X$ in $\binom{10}2=45$ pairs corresponding to selecting $2$ distinct numbers from $\{1,2,...,10\}$ and taking the larger one as $Y$. The probability is$$\frac{\binom{10}2}{100}=0.45.$$